# Parameters passing in Java

Tags: java, parameter-passing

I have a Long object in a class, I give it a value and then I pass it to another class' constructor, where it is changed. Why are the changes NOT visible in the first object?

The code:

```
public class ClassA {
    private Long t;

    public ClassA() {
        t = new Long(10);
        System.out.println(t); // prints 10
        new ClassB(t); // it is modified (see ClassB)
        System.out.println(t); // prints 10 again
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ClassA();
    }
}

class ClassB {
    private Long p;

    public ClassB(Long p) {
        this.p = p;
        this.p = this.p + 1;
        System.out.println(this.p); // prints 11
    }
}
```

The output is: 10 11 10
The Long variable is initialized in ClassA. Then I pass it to ClassB, modify it and clearly the changes are not visible in the first class. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because the `Long` class is immutable; once an instance is created, it can never change.

In this line:

```
this.p = this.p + 1;
```

what you are doing is create a *new* `Long` object. Other examples of immutable classes include all "wrapper" classes for primitive numeric types (`Byte`, `Short` etc) and `String`.

What doesn't help is that it makes the `+` operator unintuitive; what *really* does not help is that the language allows `+` on all of these immutable classes.

What happens in the above line could be written as (although it happens differently in the bytecode, I suspect):

```
long tmp = this.p.longValue();
tmp += 1;
this.p = new Long(tmp);
```

You can also verify immutability by marking your `p` as `final` in class `B`, which means the *reference* `p` can never change; `this.p = this.p + 1` will raise a compile error since you attempt to modify reference `p`.

Comment: Ooops ..that too.Its wrld famous immutable Object :P.

Comment: Immutable or not has absolutely NOTHING to do with it. Assigning to a reference NEVER changes the object it pointed to, regardless of type.

Comment: @newacct the OP expected that what happend was something like `this.p.add(1)`.

Answer (score 2):

this line `this.p = this.p + 1;` does not modify p, it creates a new `Long` from adding the two values `p` and `1` and then sets `this.p` to be a reference to this new `Long`. Objects of the class `Long` do not have mutator methods so they can never change (within Class B `this.p` was not changed, `this.p` became a reference to a **new** Long)

So the behaviour is actually

```
this.p=p;
Long newLong=this.p + 1;
this.p=newLong;
```

What you're imagining is

```
this.p=p
this.p.imaginaryAddLocal(1);
```

this would effect the original p, but of course this method `imaginaryAllLocal` doesn't exist because objects of the class Long are immutable

Comment: "but of course this method imaginaryAllLocal doesn't exist because objects of the class Long are immutable" It's the other way around -- Long is immutable because imaginaryAllLocal doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, `Long` is immutable. It means you cannot change the value that you set in the constructor (note the absence of `set` methods).

When you do

```
this.p = this.p + 1;
```

Java does.

1) Autoconvert `this.p`to its long value (primitive)

2) Arithmetic operation

3) Autoconvert the result back to a new, different Long and assign the reference to `this.p`

`t` continues pointing, all the time, to the original `Long` object.

In Java, you modify objects through its attributes (not adviceable, you should make them `private`) or its methods. A `+` (or other operator) will never change an object state (although it may create a new one, in the only case of `myString1 + myString2`)

Answer (score 0):

1- You are just modifying the p member of class B

2- Everything is passed by value (and not by reference) in Java

Comment: "Everything is passed by value (and not by reference) in Java" thats a **huge can of worms**, a reference is passed by value

Comment: @RichardTingle: What he said is absolutely true. Every value in Java is either a primitive or a reference.

Comment: I'm not saying monrow is "wrong", in fact its technically true, but without explanation point 2 is misleading

Answer (score -1):

The `Long` class is immutable, so you can not pass back the value by modifying it in the called function. In your `ClassB` a copy is created and the original value is never changed.

If you want the caller to see the changed value, you must pass it back as return value.

The same is true for the other primitive wrappers and String.

Comment: Immutable or mutable has NOTHING to do with it.

Answer (score -2):

Because Java uses pass-by-reference. This means that it passes a **copy** of the variable, and not a reference to the "original" one.

E.g. in C++, you can do this:

```
void change_var(int &x)
{
    x = 2;
}

int x = 10;
change_var(x);
std::cout << x << std::endl;
```

This would print `2`, since the reference to the variable `x` is being passed, and **not** a copy.

Comment: Well, yes and no, java passes a copy of the reference to the object. The object itself is not copied. This is important because (for non immutable classes) you could write this.p=p, this.p.someMutatorMethod() and the original p **would** be affected

Comment: Java has only pass-by-value.

Comment: That is of course true, but its one of those thing (especially the bit about copying the variable) that when said to the expert who already understands makes them think "interesting, I suppose that is true" but makes the beginner more confused. An answer thats only useful to someone who already understands isnt useful at all. Hence "well yes and no"